# Crear funciones con parametros en R

Tags: r, funciones, parametros, vectores

Creo una funcion con parametros

```
arma_function<-function(y,param){
    param<-c("c","phi","theta")
    as.numeric(factor(param))
    T<-seq(1:length(y))
    mu[1]<-param[["c"]]/(1-param[["theta"]])
    eps[1]<-y[1]-mu[1]  
    for (t in 2:lengt(T)){
      mu[t]<-param[["c"]]+param[["phi"]]*y[t-1]+param[["theta"]]*eps[t-1]
      eps[t]<-y[t]-mu[t]
    return(c(mu[t],eps[t]))
    }
}
```

Cargo la libreria datasets

```
library(datasets)
```

Creo las variables con los valores que pasare a la función

```
y <- as.numeric(Nile)
param <- c(mean(y)*(1-0.9), 0.9, -0.5)

Intento leer los valores creados en la función.  
arma <- arma_function(y, param)
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Error in param[["c"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunos cambios a la función y ahora funciona, aunque no sé si el resultado es el que buscas. El output es una lista de pares, es decir, una lista de vectores numéricos con dos elementos cada una, `mu` y `eps`.

```
arma_function <- function(y, param) {
  out <- list()                           #Creo una lista vacía en la que armará el output
  names(param) <- c("c", "phi", "theta")  #Con [["theta"]] y similares usas los nombres de los argumentos. 
  #print(param)
  as.numeric(factor(param))   #No sé que hace esta línea
  T <- seq(1:length(y))
  #print(T)
  mu <- param[["c"]] / (1 - param[["theta"]])  #A mu[1] le quité el [1] porque usas la primera ubicación. De lo contrario tienes que definir primero un vector vacío mu 
  eps <- y[1] - mu[1]                          ##A eps[1] le quité el [1] porque usas la primera ubicación. De lo contrario tienes que definir primero un vector vacío eps
  #print(length(T))
  for (t in 2:length(T)) {
    mu[t] <- param[["c"]] + param[["phi"]] * y[t - 1] + param[["theta"]] * eps[t -1]
    eps[t] <- y[t] - mu[t]
    out[[t-1]] <- (c(mu[t], eps[t]))            #Incrementalmente se agregan elementos a out
  }
  out                                         #Acá se regresa el output, **después** de "llenarse" en el bucle
}
```

Había varios problemas, voy uno por uno.

El problema que te salía y pusiste en la pregunta lo tenías en esta línea:

```
  param<-c("c","phi","theta")
```

Al sobrescribir a `param` con ese vector perdías los valores numéricos que le estabas pasando a la función. Supuse que lo que querías era ponerle esos nombres para después hacer subset con param["c"]  y así, entonces lo que hice fue ponerle esos nombres sin cambiar los valores.

El segundo problema, resuelto este, era que `mu[1]` no existía. En `R` se puede nombrar sin definir antes, pero no asignar a una posición sin definir antes. Como solo usas la primera ubicación de `mu` y `eps` funciona sin usar `[]`. Cambié esas dos líneas.

El tercer problema era que al sacar el output desde dentro del bucle lo que obtenías era el resultado del último ciclo del bucle. Los anteriores se iban "sobreescribiendo". Entonces creé una lista vacía llamada `out` antes del bucle y dentro del bucle la fui llenando. Después del bucle indico que esa lista `out` es el output (no es necesario llamar explícitamente a `return()`). Usé una lista porque es lo más genérico que se me ocurrió al no saber exactamente que tipo de output esperas. Seguramente quieras modificarlo, pero la lógica sería esa.

No me detuve mucho en qué es lo que hace esa función, más bien en organizar el flujo para que no de errores y de un resultado. Sobre esa base quizás puedas adecuarla a tus necesidades.

PD: los `#print()` los fui poniendo para ver pasaba dentro de la función. Ayudan bastante, puedes descomentarlos para abrir la caja negra.